Real analysis - can someone please show me how they got this inequality?

I really don't get how they got the first inequality:
$$\frac{n+1}{3(n+1)^2+1}\frac{3n^2+1}{n}\leq \frac{3n^2+1}{3n(n+1)}.$$
How did they come up with that upper bound? Am I missing a general inequality trick here?

cancel the common $3n^2 + 1$   and multiply through by both denominators, it becomes $3n^3 + 6 n^2 + 3n < 3 n^3 + 6 n^2 + 4n.$  And the steps are reversible

Force the second fraction to be of the target form -- it's almost there already.
\begin{align*}
\frac{n+1}{3(n+1)^2+1}\frac{3n^2+1}{n}  
&= \frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+1/3}\frac{3n^2+1}{3n}   \\
&= \underbrace{\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2+1/3}}_{\forall n \in \Bbb{Z},\ 3/4 \,\leq \text{ this } < \,1}\frac{3n^2+1}{3n(n+1)}   \\
{} &< \frac{3n^2+1}{3n(n+1)}
\end{align*}

$$
\frac{n+1}{3(n+1)^2+1}\frac{3n^2+1}{n} = \frac{1}{3(n+1)+1/(n+1)}\frac{3n^2+1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{3(n+1)}\frac{3n^2+1}{n}.
$$
In the last step we use the fact that for $n \geq 0$ we have $3(n+1)+1/(n+1)\geq 3(n+1)$.

HINT
Notice that $3n(n + 1)^{2} + n > 3n(n + 1)^{2}$ and $3n(n + 1) > 3n^{2} +1$.

$$\require{cancel}\frac{n+1}{3(n+1)^2+1}\frac{\cancel{3n^2+1}}{\cancel n}\leq \frac{\cancel{3n^2+1}}{3\cancel n(n+1)}$$
$$\iff \frac{n+1}{3(n+1)^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{3(n+1)}$$
$$\iff \frac{3(n+1)^2}{3(n+1)^2+1} \leq 1.$$

cancelling $3n^2+1$ was suggested in a comment by Will Jagy
